# Windows Server 2008 Standard VM Licenses

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I'm looking at buying Windows Server 2008 Standard. From what I can gather this will let me install the physical os and one virtual os. What licenses would I then need to be able to add some extra virtual os's?

Many Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install additional Windows Server 2008 virtual machines you would need one Server 2008 Standard licence per virtual machine you want to add.

Server 2008 Enterprise allows you to install four virtual machines per licence.

If you have the cash and hardware then Server 2008 Datacenter allows unlimited virtual machines per licence on the same physical host.

[Microsoft Licensing FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx#virt)

Comment: Please note this is specific to R2 as far as I am aware.

Comment: This is for both 2008 and 2008 R2